# How do you create a SimpleBeanInfo in the year 2016?

Tags: java, javabeans

I'd like to create a property editor for my Java Beans. For that I need a class that implements [BeanInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html). The problem: I really don't feel comfortable with declaring an attribute name as String like this (`floodColor`, `fillColor`, `percent`):

```
import java.beans.*;
public class BarChartBeanBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo
{
    private final static Class myClass = BarChartBean.class;

    public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors()
    {
        try {
            PropertyDescriptor flc = new PropertyDescriptor("floodColor", myClass);
            PropertyDescriptor fic = new PropertyDescriptor("fillColor", myClass);
            PropertyDescriptor pct = new PropertyDescriptor("percent", myClass);

            PropertyDescriptor[] list = { flc, fic, pct };
            return list;
        }
        catch (IntrospectionException iexErr)
        {
            throw new Error(iexErr.toString());
        }
    }

};
```

I got this from an example article about how to create a custom property editor: [The trick to controlling bean customization](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077063/learn-java/the-trick-to-controlling-bean-customization.html?page=2). The article is from the year 1997.

How do you create a property editor in the year 2016 without using string declarations of variables which obviously will lead to runtime exceptions once someone changes the variable name?

I mean other than to use the Introspector. Is there e. g. some kind of annotation support for attribute names of classes?

Thank you very much for the expertise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with custom annotations, it seems to work. At least it's typesafe now and coupled to the fields.

**Code**

ExampleBean.java

```
import annotations.Descriptor;
import annotations.Property;

@Descriptor(displayName = "Example Bean", shortDescription = "This is an example bean")
public class ExampleBean {

    @Property(displayName = "Integer Value", shortDescription = "This is an integer value")
    int integerValue;

    @Property(displayName = "Double Value", shortDescription = "This is a double value")
    double doubleValue;

    @Property(displayName = "String Value", shortDescription = "This is a string value")
    String stringValue;

    public int getIntegerValue() {
        return integerValue;
    }

    public void setIntegerValue(int integerValue) {
        this.integerValue = integerValue;
    }

    public double getDoubleValue() {
        return doubleValue;
    }

    public void setDoubleValue(double doubleValue) {
        this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public void setStringValue(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

}
```

Descriptor.java

```
package annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Descriptor {

    public String displayName() default "";

    public String shortDescription() default "";

}
```

Property.java

```
package annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Property {

    public String displayName() default "";

    public String shortDescription() default "";

}
```

ExampleBeanBeanInfo.java

```
import java.beans.BeanDescriptor;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.beans.SimpleBeanInfo;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import annotations.Descriptor;
import annotations.Property;

public class ExampleBeanBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo {

    private final static Class<ExampleBean> myClass = ExampleBean.class;

    public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {

        List<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            for (Field field : myClass.getDeclaredFields()) {

                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Property.class)) {

                    Annotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(Property.class);
                    Property property = (Property) annotation;

                    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(field.getName(), myClass);
                    propertyDescriptor.setDisplayName(property.displayName());
                    propertyDescriptor.setShortDescription(property.shortDescription());

                    propertyDescriptors.add(propertyDescriptor);
                }

            }

            return propertyDescriptors.toArray(new PropertyDescriptor[propertyDescriptors.size()]);
        } catch (Exception iexErr) {
            throw new Error(iexErr.toString());
        }
    }

    public BeanDescriptor getBeanDescriptor() {
        BeanDescriptor desc = new BeanDescriptor(myClass);

        if (myClass.isAnnotationPresent(Descriptor.class)) {

            Annotation annotation = myClass.getAnnotation(Descriptor.class);
            Descriptor descriptor = (Descriptor) annotation;

            desc.setDisplayName(descriptor.displayName());
            desc.setShortDescription(descriptor.shortDescription());

        }

        return desc;
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
import java.beans.BeanDescriptor;
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IntrospectionException {

        BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(ExampleBean.class);

        BeanDescriptor beanDescriptor = beanInfo.getBeanDescriptor();

        System.out.printf( "Bean display name = '%s', description = '%s'\n", beanDescriptor.getDisplayName(), beanDescriptor.getShortDescription());

        PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();

        for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {

            String propertyName = propertyDescriptor.getName();

            System.out.printf("Property field name = '%s', display name = '%s', description = '%s'\n", propertyName, propertyDescriptor.getDisplayName(), propertyDescriptor.getShortDescription());

        }

        System.exit(0);
        ;
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Bean display name = 'Example Bean', description = 'This is an example bean'
Property field name = 'doubleValue', display name = 'Double Value', description = 'This is a double value'
Property field name = 'integerValue', display name = 'Integer Value', description = 'This is an integer value'
Property field name = 'stringValue', display name = 'String Value', description = 'This is a string value'
```

This example exposes the displayname and shortdescription methods, one would have to add others of the bean and property descriptor.

If anyone has a better way, please let me know.